# multer node.js upload images got a 500 internet server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I tried to upload image file to node.js but got a 500 internal server error. This is my server side code.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: './public/uploads',
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            switch (file.mimetype) {
                case 'image/jpeg':
                    ext = '.jpeg';
                    break;
                case 'image/png':
                    ext = '.png';
                    break;
            }
            cb(null, file.originalname + ext);
        }
    });

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/upload_photo', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res, next) {

    //save filename to db
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

On cilent side I simply use ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/upload_photo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false
    })
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: error stack trace please.

Comment: @MukeshSharma no error that's strange

Answer (score 2):

I used postman for testing the api and I came to know about the error In my case it was "path does not exists error" since I didn't not created that destination folder in which I am storing the images

For eg:-

```
destination: './public/uploads',
```

In my case there is no folder name uploads inside public that's why I got server error 500